# Can an ellipse be drawn on google maps in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, ellipse

I want to draw an ellipse on google maps in my android app. I have already drawn circle but now I want to draw ellipse. Is there a way to draw an ellipse?

This is how I am drawing the circle:

```
private void drawMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position) {

    int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
    int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000; //opaque red fill

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

How should I change this code to make ellipse type shape?

Comment: You will need to disclose how you draw the circle and why you fail to generalize that to an ellipse.

Comment: i did't get your point

Comment: Show what you did (code) and explain where you are stuck. This will considerably help people to help you :)

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Improved grammar & capitalization and removed blockquote around final request for an answer in order to improve chances of this question gaining some traction.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but I faced the same issue, so I will explain how I solved it. As far as I know there is no Ellipse feature on Google maps, the approach I use is to draw a polygon, calculating the vertices using the parametric equation of the ellipse. 
If you have the center of the ellipse and two radius:

```
for (var angle = 1; angle <= 360; angle++)//360 points
 {
       var py = center.Latitude + semiMajor * Math.Cos(radians * angle);
       var px = center.Longitude + semiMinor * Math.Sin(radians * angle);
       point = new LatLng(py, px);
       polygon.Points.Add(point);
  }
```

You can increase the angle variable by more than 1 in order to get less points. You can check [this post](https://csharpvault.com/blog/drawing-ellipses-google-maps/) for the entire example.
Hope it helps!